# calling wcf restful web service to insert data into database from c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

written a rest web service, and a asp.net registration page, user entered data sent to web service, c# code is written below.

```
try
{
    string posturl = "serverurl/insertInfo/";
    string id = sid.Text;
    string pas = regpw.Text;
    string nam = sname.Text;
    string mob = smob.Text;
    string email = semail.Text;
    string addre = sadd.Text;
    string st = "pending";
    string finalurl = posturl + id + "/" + pas + "/" + nam + "/" + mob + "/" + 
                      email + "/" + addre + "/" + st;
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(finalurl);
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    req.KeepAlive = false;
    req.Timeout = 5000;
    Stream poststresm = req.GetRequestStream();
    poststresm.Close();
    //HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    //StreamReader red = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
    //Console.WriteLine("response");
    //Console.WriteLine(red.ReadToEnd().ToString());
    //Console.ReadKey();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

Comment: Arrr...what be the problem matey?

Comment: data is not inserting into the database, if i remove the comments for the response , i was getting an error webException. (my web service does not return  any thing .